# jQuery selector from $.get()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have some code to fetch data using $.get(), and that pulls the entire page in HTML fine.

How do I go about using selectors on that get data and pulling certain data from elements as I would using $('.someclass') in a normal page?

Comment: you can't use a selector like `$('.someclass')` because the loaded html might not be added to the dom... instead `data` is having the loaded html string you can do something like `$(data).find('.someclass')`

Comment: How do I get $.get data to go from an object to text/strings/something I can work with using find? I keep getting an object returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just text until you insert it into the DOM somehow. You could have a hidden DIV and do:

```
$('#myhiddendiv').html( data_from_get );
```

and then search the descendants of #myhiddendiv.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [plugin](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-get-enhanced/) then you can use the following like jQuery.load() does.

```
/************************************************
jquery.get-enhanced plugin v0.10
Author: www.benbarnett.net || @benpbarnett

Copyright (c) 2011 Ben Barnett
Licensed under the MIT license
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*************************************************/
(function(b,j){b.get=function(a,c,d,e){var f=a.indexOf(" ");if(f>=0){var k=a.slice(f,a.length);a=a.slice(0,f)}else return j.apply(this,arguments);if(b.isFunction(c)){e=e||d;d=c;c=null}var l=/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi;return b.ajax({type:"GET",url:a,data:c,success:function(h,g){var i="";if(g==="success"||g==="notmodified")i=b("<div>").append(h.replace(l,"")).find(k).html();d&&d.apply(this,[i,g,h])},dataType:e})}})(jQuery,jQuery.get);
```

You can use like this:

```
// use space    VV and add class or id which you want to get
$.get( "url.html .someclass", function( data ) {
    $( ".where_to_insert_data" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: That type of URL works for `.load()`, are you sure it works for `.get()`?

Comment: @Barmar I think it should work. http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-get-enhanced/

Comment: You have to use that extra plugin to get this feature, it's not part of standard jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

say if your `GET` response data in variable like this `response` then you can find any selector in it using this

```
$(response).find('selector');
```

hope it helps